# Quill container blot

Tags: javascript, quill

I can't wrap all blots with container blot or i can't create container blot.

I expect

```
<main><p>this is first paragraph</p><p>this is second paragraph</p></main>
```

when i register new blot as block, it replaces all p tags but i need container blot.

```
var Block = Quill.import('blots/block');
        class Main extends Block {
            static create() {
                var node = super.create();
                return node;
            }
        }

        Main.blotName = 'main';
        Main.tagName = 'main';

        Quill.register(Main);
```

This one doesn't work

```
var Container = Quill.import('blots/container');
        class Main extends Container {}

        Main.blotName = 'main';
        Main.tagName = 'main';

        Quill.register(Main);
```

Comment: Hey @tunc. Have you ever found a solution to this? I too have the same issue with Quill.

Comment: no. I solved my problem via change all structure

Comment: Hi, @Tunc. Could you please share your solution with the rest of the community?

Comment: @Loa i didn't use quill because of this problem. I mentioned in my comment above.